# Gcloud load balancing to the same host for two TCP connections

Tags: load-balancing, gcloud, session-affinity

I'm using GCP like in the following schema:

1. TCP balancer -> backend-service -> MIG(my app) with auto scaling.

"My app" accepts commands on a TCP port (A) and sends notifications on another TCP port(B) for subscriber.

I'm running my tests against TCP LB's IP - my tests connect to port B on a startup(i.e. one of instances of "my app") and also my tests make a connection to port A for each test.

i.e. I've faced with a case when port A and port B are terminated/connected to different hosts.

I am not sure how to circumvent this case.

Comment: could you please elaborate what error message you're getting while executing the above setup. Also check for [TCP proxy load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp) setup for two TCP connections.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mitigated the issue using --session-affinity=CLIENT_IP for backend-services configuration, I.e. all connections from one IP are directed to the same target.